# Check whether an undirected graph contains a simple cycle of length four using the "Squares" method

Tags: algorithms, graphs

The following problem is exercise 4.3 of the book ["Algorithms"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073523402) by S. Dasgupta, C. Papadimitriou, and U. Vazirani.

> *Squares.* Design and analyze an algorithm that takes as input an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ and determines whether $G$ contains a simple cycle (i.e., a cycle which does not intersect itself) of length four in $O(|V|^{3})$ time.

This can be solved by checking for each pair of vertices $u$ and $v$ whether they share at least two common neighbors; see [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/199702/28199).

However, in the book, the authors gave a single-word hint: *Squares*.

Following the hint, I square the adjacency matrix $M$ of $G$ twice (i.e., $M \to M^2 \to M^4$) and check whether $M^4[i][i]$ is true for some $i$. But this attempt fails because it produces "false positives" by treating $a-b-a-b-a$ or $a-b-c-b-a$ as cycles of length four.

How to fix the "false positives" in the squaring method above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square $M$, to get $M^2$.  Write $M^2 = D + P$, where $D$ is the diagonal part (all non-diagonal entries are zero) and $P$ is the non-diagonal part (all diagonal entries are zero).

Compute $Q=P^2$.  Note that $Q_{aa}$ counts the number of ways to start at $a$ and end at $a$, excluding cycles of the form $ababa$ and $abaca$ etc., but not avoiding cycles of the form $abcba$.

Now compute $R = MDM - D$.  Note that $R_{aa}$ counts the number of cycles of the form $abcba$ where $c \ne a$.

Let $S = Q-R$.  We find that $S_{aa}$ counts the number of simple 4-cycles that start and end at $a$.  Thus, the graph has a simple 4-cycle if and only if one or more of the diagonal entries of $S$ are non-zero.

Comment: Note that $R_{aa}$ also counts cycles of the form $ababa$.

Comment: Therefore you need to take $R = MDM - D$, or alternatively $S = Q - R + D$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly different (but equivalent) approach. The entry $(M^4)_{ii}$ computes the number of walks $i\to j\to k\to \ell\to i$. These are either squares (if all of $i,j,k,\ell$ are different), or of the form $i \to j \to i \to \ell \to i$ (possibly $j = \ell$), or of the form $i \to j \to k \to j \to i$. There are exactly $d(i)^2$ of the second type (here $d(i)$ is the degree of $i$, equal to $(M^2)_{ii}$) and exactly $\sum_{k \neq i} (M^2)_{ik}^2$ of the third type. So $(M^4)_{ii} > \sum_k (M^2)_{ik}^2$ iff there is a square through $i$.

Note that this actually gives an $O(|V|^\omega)$ algorithm for detecting squares, where $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication constant (the best known bound, $\omega < 2.373$, is due to Le Gall).